# Many Command Line Tools installed by Xcode and downloaded manually

Tags: command-line, xcode, development

I have a command line tools installed by Xcode 12 and I would like to install an older version of command line tools but without installing older Xcode.

1. I have installed Xcode 12 which comes with Command Line Tools
2. I have download and installed (pkg file) Command Line Tools version 11.5

Installation of tools from second point finished with success but I don't know where it was installed.

Questions:

- Is it possible to have a Command Line Tools installed by Xcode and another version of Command Line Tools installed without Xcode?
- How to list available Command Line Tools versions and theirs paths?